# Арифметические действия в sql запросе

Tags: mysql

Нужно обновить в базе информацию, если с момента изменения прошло больше 3-х суток. Поле `last_edit` содержит время в формате UNIX. Делаю так:

```
$last_edit = 259200; // 3 суток
$this_time = time() - $last_edit; // сколько прошло
$db->query( "UPDATE tablename set status = '0' WHERE last_edit >= ({$this_time} - last_edit) AND revision = '1'" );
```

В результате изменяются данные постоянно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логично

```
last_edit >= ({$this_time} - last_edit)
2 * last_edit >= $this_time
```

любая дата обновления, умноженная на два, будет больше текущей даты.

Должно быть

```
UPDATE tablename set status = 0 WHERE last_edit <= {$this_time} AND revision = 1
```

А еще лучше убрать переменную `$this_time` вообще

```
UPDATE tablename set status = 0 WHERE last_edit <= NOW() - 3600 * 24 * 3 AND revision = 1
```

P.S. И не нужно в запросе числа обрамлять в кавычки

Comment: Не совсем понял как написать...

Comment: @Владимир Так понятно?

Comment: Да, но так не работает

Comment: Логика вроде правильная, но в итоге данные все равно изменяются.

Comment: @Владимир приведите пример конкретной записи, которая должна изменится, а не меняется. Интересуют поля `status`, `last_edit`, `revision`

Comment: Добавил скрин в опросе

Comment: @Владимир last_edit = 1524860008 = GMT: Friday, 27 April 2018 г., 20:13:28. С какого перепугу должно обновляться?

Comment: Прошу прощения, все правильно) Я не в ту сторону изменял last_edit что бы проверить)